# How to change default PM2 table name user to administartor?

Tags: nestjs, pm2

[PM2 table configuration server of nest-js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n2j7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step:1 PM2-configuration:

1.npm install -g pm2

2.pm2 list

3.pm2 status

4.pm2 start dist/main.js --name appname

5.pm2 save

6.pm2 monit

7.pm2 logs

8.pm2 kill

step-2 If u want the the saved app:

9.pm2 resurrect

step-3 ecosystem-file configuration:

10.pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand if you tidied up the formatting and maybe added some explanation to help summarize what you're doing. Can you [edit] your answer to help us out?